# Терминология функций Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, функции, классы

Объясните пожалуйста проще эти понятия:

**init** - функция которая будет инициализировать/активировать свойства класса для определенного объекта, после создания и сопоставления с соответствующим классом.

**self** - представляет объект, который наследует эти свойства.

Для чего писать повторы self.month = month?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: self.month это переменная, которая будет доступная в любом месте класса для дальнейшего использования.  Вы ей присваиваете значение, которое передаете при инициализации объекта класса.

Comment: Я Вам такую простыню про классы написал, а Вы даже ответ не приняли... И да, если б Вы её всё-таки внимательно прочитали, то поняли бы, что `self.что-то` – атрибут класса, а то, что стоит в правой части оператора присваивания, это аргументы конструктора (как и аргументы любой другой функции). Вам не обязательно их так присваивать, как в этом примере. Это лишь один из вариантов развития событий.

Comment: V-Mor, Извиняюсь, не знал как принимать в ответ, исправился, спасибо.

Comment: Ничего страшного, осваивайтесь :) И, раз так, держите ещё один ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начать, думаю, стоит с того, что `self` используется, чтобы показать, что то, что идёт после него через `.`, – член класса. То есть просто `month` – обычная переменная, а `self.month` – атрибут класса.

Теперь о Вашем примере. Не буду долго распространяться про отдельный котёл в аду, который ждёт Вас за то, что код вставлен картинкой и мне теперь его руками надо переписывать вместо такого привычного Ctrl+C Ctrl+V... Итак, Вам просто попался такой пример, где не очень наглядно описывается, что данная конструкция не обязательно может быть такой. Во-первых, аргументы конструктора (те, что в скобках после `__init__`) отнюдь не обязаны иметь имена такие же, как у атрибутов класса (те, что после `self.`). Так что, для начала отмечу, что вот так тоже может быть:

```python
class Date:
    def __init__(self, mm, dd, yyyy):
        self.month = mm
        self.day = dd
        self.year = yyyy
```

Здесь, как видите, уже нет никакого дублирования, а работать будет точно так же.

Теперь немного о том, что же там всё-таки происходит. Когда Вы создаёте объект `Date`, Вы передаёте ему три аргумента (первый – `self` – передаётся автоматически). Например `today = Date(19, 3, 2021)`. Вот эти три аргумента передаются в метод `__init__` Вашего только что созданного объекта `today` и становятся в нём аргументами `mm`, `dd`, `yyyy` соответственно. Потом они присваиваются атрибутам этого объекта соответственно `self.month`, `self.day` и `self.year`. То есть становятся свойствами объекта `today` и теперь Вы можете, вызвав `print(today.year)` узнать, какой сегодня год. Если бы этого присваивания не было, атрибуты `self.month`, `self.day` и `self.year` не были бы созданы и Вы так и остались бы в неведении насчёт года. Так что это не просто дублирование, это создание атрибутов и присваивание им значений из аргументов конструктора.

Теперь насчёт того, почему создатели языка не упростили эту конструкцию и заставляют нас присваивать все аргументы подряд атрибутам. На самом деле, мы можем сделать с этими аргументами что угодно или не делать с ними ничего. Например:

Не делать ничего (плохой пример, не стоит так делать):

```python
# Вечно 2007ой
class Date: 
    def __init__(self, mm, dd, yyyy):
        self.month = 1 # плевать мне на аргументы, мой класс, какие хочу значения у атрибутов, такие и задаю
        self.day = 1
        self.year = 2007
```

Делать что угодно (лучше что-то полезное):

```python
class Date:
    def __init__(self, mm, dd, yyyy):

        if (mm < 1) or (mm > 12): # Например, проверка на корректность значений
            print('Incorrect month')
            return
        self.month = mm

        if (dd < 1) or (dd > 31):
            print('Incorrect day')
            return
        self.day = dd

        self.year = yyyy
```

Заключение – не стоит забывать, что `__init__` – такой же метод класса, как остальные. Он так же принимает аргументы и может делать с ними что угодно. Конечно, классический и простой вариант – просто создание атрибутов и присваивание им значений из аргументов. Но этот вариант далеко не единственный. Вы можете совершить какие-то вычисления с этими аргументами и присвоить атрибутам результаты вычислений, можете передать аргументы базовому классу, можете создать ещё несколько объектов других классов, запустить что-то... В общем, что угодно на Ваше усмотрение.

P.S. Ну и, как обычно: это моё субъективное мнение, не претендующее на абсолютную истину, т.к. в Python я далеко не эксперт. Исправления и уточнения приветствуются в комментариях.